The closure of a connected set must be connected
I tried to prove that if $f: \text{Cl} A \to Y$ is a continuous map from the closure of a connected set $A$ to a discrete space $Y$, then $f$ must be constant. Since $A$ is connected, $f$ restricted to $A$ must be constant, so assume $f (A) = y$. Then, since $\{y\}$ is a clopen subset of $Y$, its inverse image must be clopen. Now, $f^{-1} (y)$ is a superset of $A$ and a subset of $\text{Cl} A$ and since $\text{Cl} A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, we must have either $f^{-1} (y) = A$ or $f^{-1} (y) = \text{Cl} A$. If $A = \text{Cl} A$, we are done. If not, then $A$ is open and not closed, so $f^{-1} (y) = A$ cannot be clopen and we are done.
Am I correct?

Welcome to math SE. Have a look at mathjax for your mathematical expressions.


and since $\text{Cl} A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, we must have either $f^{-1} (y) = A$ or $f^{-1} (y) = \text{Cl} A$.

I don't quite follow this step in your proof. What you've shown up to this point is that, given an arbitrary continuous function $f: \text{Cl} A \to Y$, where $Y$ is discrete, then $B = f^{-1} (f (A))$ is closed and open in $\text{Cl} A$ due to the fact that the singleton $f (A)$ is closed and open in $Y$. I would proceed as follows.
Suppose there is an element $x$ in $\text{Cl} A$ such that $f (x) \ne f (A)$. Note that this means $x \notin B$. Because $B$ is closed in $\text{Cl} A$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\text{Cl} A$ such that $U$ misses $B$. But $x$ being in $\text{Cl} A$ implies that $U$ intersects $A$. Since $A \subseteq B$, then $U$ intersects $B$, which is a contradiction. So, $f$ must be constant on $\text{Cl} A$ (everywhere equal to $f (A)$), which is what you set out to show.
Note that we did not even use the fact that $B$ is open.
Edit: I now understand your reasoning. We can make it simpler. Since $\text{Cl} A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, and the set $B = f^{-1} (f (A)) \supseteq A$ is closed (and contained in $\text{Cl} A$), then we have immediately that $B = \text{Cl} A$.

Another way.
Let $A$ be connected set. Assume that its closure $\bar A$ is disconnected. Then, there are two disjoint open sets $U_1,U_2$ such that $A\subset\bar A\subset U_1\cup U_2$ and $\bar A\cap U_1\neq\emptyset$ and $\bar A\cap U_2\neq\emptyset$. Since $A$ is connected, $A$ must be contained in one of $U_1,U_2$, say in $U_1.$ But then there is an $x\in U_2\cap\partial A$ and $U_2$ being a neighboorhood of $x$ must cut $A.$ Contradiction.
